# Grid view with SqlDatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have in my Web a `GridView` that use `SqlDatasource` to insert data into the rows of the gridview.

the grid have for example:
id
name
genre_id

now i have a table with songs and table with genres(genre_id,genre_name), and i want that in the grid will use genres_name and not the genres_id

This is the `SqlDataSource` for the GridView:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="StationsDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TvSQLManagerConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [id],[name],[genre] FROM songs ORDER BY [name]" 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SQL Join` to get data from Genre table as well.

Replace your Query in `SelectCommand` like this

```
SELECT S.ID,S.NAME.G.GENRE_NAME AS GENRE FROM SONGS S
INNER JOIN 
GENERES G ON S.GENRE=G.GENRE_ID
```

Comment: The problem is that i define in the gridview genre as the DataField of his colmun,and then he except to get genre but he get G.GENRE_NAME and he give me an error when i run it

Comment: @MTA : Either change the name in datagrid or change the query to have an alias ( i updated my answer for this)